# Group together key value pairs in dictionary with a common value

Tags: python, dictionary

Given the following dictionary:

```
 my_dict = {
 'Admin.Email': 'admin@domein.nl',
 'Admin.Name': 'Admin Account',
 'Admin.Phone': '+31 6 12345678',
 'Admin.RipeID': 'nan',
 'Loc.Address': 'Testraat 100',
 'Loc.Country': 'Nederland',
 'Loc.Place': 'Plaatsnaam',
 'Loc.Postalcode': '1234AB',
 'Org.Address': 'Testraat 100',
 'Org.Country': 'Nederland',
 'Org.Email': 'email@domein.nl',
 'Org.Name': 'Bedrijfsnaam',
 'Org.Place': 'Plaatsnaam',
 'Org.Postalcode': '1234AB',
 'Org.RipeID': 'nan',
 'Tech.Email': 'tech@domein.nl',
 'Tech.Name': 'Tech Account',
 'Tech.Phone': '+31 6 87654321',
 'Tech.RipeID': 'nan',
 'Technische contactpersoon': 'nan'
}
```

I want to group together all key value pairs that have a common name (like admin or tech) so that I can easily find the value corresponding to its key based on the groupname. Desired result would be something like this:

```
 new_dict = {
     'attributes': {
         'admin': [
             {
                 'name': 'email' 
                 'value: 'admin@domein.nl',
             },
             {
                 'name': 'name'
                 'value': 'Admin Account'
             },
             {
                 'name': 'phone',
                 'value': '+31 6 12345678'
             },
             {
                 'name': 'ripeid'
                 'value': 'nan'
             }
         ],
         'tech': [
             {
                 'name': 'email' 
                 'value: 'tech@domein.nl',
             },
             {
                 'name': 'name'
                 'value': 'Tech Account'
             },
             {
                 'name': 'phone',
                 'value': '+31 6 87654321'
             },
             {
                 'name': 'ripeid'
                 'value': 'nan'
             }
         ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. What have you tried and what problems did you run into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your desired output is to have the key-value pairs grouped together based on their common name:
You can run a for loop on your dictionary, then split the key to get the group name and attribute name and then you have to append a new dictionary with the correct attribute name and value to the right group.

```
new_dict = {
    'attributes': {}
}

for key, value in my_dict.items():
    # Because your attributes and names are divided by '.'
    group_name, attribute_name = key.split(".", 1)

    # Because attributes and names are coming in capitalised manner, but you want lowercase
    group_name = group_name.lower()
    attribute_name = attribute_name.lower()

    # Check if the group already exists, if not, add a new key
    if group_name not in new_dict['attributes']:
        new_dict['attributes'][group_name] = []

    # Append dictionary to the correct key
    new_dict['attributes'][group_name].append({
        'name': attribute_name,
        'value': value
    })

print(new_dict)
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I did try a few things but got one error after the other which means I did not have any code ready to show what I have tried.

Comment: Np, please accept as an answer if it worked @Beeelze